# Derivate R package

Tags: r, derivative

I'm trying to derivate a function in R using the Deriv package. The function is a weighted gaussian kernel, so I implemented the following solution :

```
library(Deriv)
library(psych)

x <- matrix(0:19, nrow = 4, ncol = 5)
w <- c(1,0.5,1,0.1,0.5)

eudis = function(x) {
  xp2 <- as.matrix(apply(x^2, 1, sum))
  xp2 %+% t(xp2) - 2*x%*%t(x)
}
wf <- function(w, x, gamma=1) {
  exp(-gamma*as.matrix(eudis(t(t(x) * w))))
}

Deriv(wf(w,x=x), "w")
```

But this is returning an error :

> Error in eval(expr) : dim(X) must have a positive length

I have the impression, Deriv can only compute basic function. How can I automatically compute the derivative of a kernel function ?

Comment: you might have to do this one by hand ...

Comment: Yes, it might be possible, but I would like to automize the process. To be able to compute multiple kernel functions. This function is an exemple but it could be a different one. There is no package in R close to what can do autograd in python ?

Comment: try the "madness" package, or possibly TMB ...